# Entity Framework connection work locally but not on remote server after deploy

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string, web-hosting

I have created a web application in ASP.NET MVC using a SQL Server database, and I used Entity Framework with a database-first approach.

This is my connection string for Entity Framework

```
<add name="AcModelFinalContext" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Maha-Earth-Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Maha-Earth-Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Maha-Earth-Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-IE0U7PA\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=AC-Services;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

This connection string is working fine on localhost.

For deployment I made made changes in string as

```
<add name="AcModelFinalContext" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Maha-Earth-Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Maha-Earth-Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Maha-Earth-Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=dburl.com\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=AC-Services;integrated security=True;User Id=mydb;Password=mypass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

but this does not work.

Comment: You should hide user/password off your connection string "asap"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove `integrated security=True`.
When you use this option, User/Password is not used.

You should also try to remove `\SQLEXPRESS`. I don't think your provider is using Sql-Server Express.